# How to fake an older version of SQL Server to support legacy application code

Tags: sql-server, foxpro

I have legacy application that checks to see if the version of SQL Server is 6.5, 7 or 2000. If not, it returns a database not supported error. I would like this application to use the database on SQL Server 2008. Is there a way to fake the version so that the application check for SQL Server version passes. My legacy application code is FoxPro. I do not have the means to recompile the FoxPro application.

Comment: this is not really recommended...  do you know what it is checking in order to determine the DB version?

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [setting the compatibility level](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-2005-change-database-compatible-level-backward-compatibility/) to 80 (which means SQL Server 2000):

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel AdventureWorks, 80;
```

Version of SQL Server database can be one of the following:

- 60 = SQL Server 6.0
- 65 = SQL Server 6.5
- 70 = SQL Server 7.0
- 80 = SQL Server 2000
- 90 = SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 3):

Applications usually verify the current server version by checking either [`@@VERSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177512.aspx) or [`SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx). Both are impossible to override or fake.

Applications that do **not** explicitly check the version can run in a database with a lower compatibility level. But if the application has code that explicitly checks one of the above, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the compatibility level of the database should work fine.  You can do this using [sp_dbcmptlevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178653.aspx)

Comment: Nope. Does not seem to work. Looks like the code is looking for server setting not database compatibility level. The darn code is in FoxPro.

Comment: I'd have to answer your question with another question - exactly what about this situation is NOT brutal?  Is it the part about not having a means to compile (IF the source is even available)?  Or is it the part about being locked into a 10 year old database (which could force you to set up a whole new server if another app you support only runs on 2005+)?  Or were you just looking to get into an idiotic argument about languages?